# WOULD+Present Perfect

Tags: present-perfect, modal-verbs, perfect-constructions

Could you please explain why Modal + Present Perfect is used here. It's usually used to express regret, but I can see none in this example.

> Personal computers first made their appearance in the home in the 1970s, but surely few people **would have been able to** imagine then that the home computer could evolve into the super-fast, super-sleek machines of today.

Comment: Please explain why you believe that "would have" is "usually used to express regret".

Comment: On a technical note, the structure is *[ "would have" + past participle ]*. The "have" is in base form following "would", not present simple.

Comment: Following on MarcInManhattan's comment, are you aware that generally speaking, tenses have more than one function? While this tense can be used to express regret, that's not all it does. English speakers didn't invent this tense just to express regret.

Comment: In practice, the version as cited doesn't differ much *semantically* from Simple Past *surely few people **imagined** then that...* And so far as I'm concerned, *in practice* the circumlocutory "modal" version means *exactly* the same regardless of whether ***would have imagined*** is extended to ***would have been able to imagine***. But I fully expect that someone will want to lecture me about how the ***being able to*** element somehow adds to the meaning.

Comment: @gotube: I hesitate to say it (I was considering closevoting on the grounds that the question is based on a false premise), but perhaps *your* comment/s should be posted as an Answer! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hah! I wanted to post it as part of an answer, but for it to be complete, I'd need to be able to express what the function is in the example sentence, and it's not coming to me. I think it's something like *[ "be able to" + past + speculative ]*, but I'm not confident enough about that to answer. The "would" is throwing me